# Python resolve ForwardRef

Tags: python, generics

I have a typing.ForwardRef object as a remnant from earlier generic programming shenanigans. At this point I know the class represented by the ForwardRef exists, but how can I retrieve this type?

A fairly minimal example of what I am doing. Convoluted solution for this example, but for the actual use case it makes sense.

```py
class GenericClass(Generic[T]):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, **kwargs) -> None:
        # retrieve the type or forwardref of T
        orig_bases = [orig_base for orig_base in cls.__orig_bases__ if get_origin(orig_base) is GenericClass]
        assert len(orig_bases) == 1
        orig_base = orig_bases[0]
        generic_types = get_args(orig_base)
        assert len(generic_types) == 1
        cls.__type_t = generic_types[0]

    def use_type(self) -> T:
        thetype = resolve_forward_refs(self.__type_t) # to be implemented
        return thetype()

class MyImpl(GenericClass["SomeType"]):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate a ForwardRef by calling `ForwardRef._evaluate(globals(), locals(), frozenset())` on it. This assumes that the type behind the forward ref is known in these namespaces, i.e. you have imported the type into the local or global scope of the module.

```py
if isinstance(myref, ForwardRef):
  myref_type = myref._evaluate(globals(), locals(), frozenset())
```

Alternative syntax:

```py
typing._eval_type(myref, globals(), locals())
```

Source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/typing.py#L849

Edit: For Python versions <3.9, leave out the third parameter to _evaluate:

```py
if isinstance(myref, ForwardRef):
  myref_type = myref._evaluate(globals(), locals())
```

Comment: That looks good, although this seems to be an internal API(underscore). Is there a public API for doing this? If not it will do, but I hope it will not change in the future.

Comment: It is internal, and it has changed in Python3.9 for example, where the recursive_guard required parameter was added. Therefore the function signature differs between those versions and you'll need to perform different calls depending on the version if you plan to support both. I've updated the original answer to reflect this.

Comment: You can instead use pydantic's `from pydantic.typing import evaluate_forwardref` to avoid using a private method. It does the same thing (using `_evaluate` under the hood), but is a bit more careful to ensure that mypy won't complain.

Comment: Sure, if you're already using pydantic, definitely do so. But not a general-purpose solution, unfortunately.